# Facebook Graph API: read messages in v2.8

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-fql

since `read_mailbox` is deprecated, I was wondering if there's still a possibility to get all of my messages via API or any other service?

> /v2.4/{user_id}/notifications operations as well as read_stream, read_mailbox, and manage_notifications permissions are deprecated in v2.4.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no possibility to get access to the user messages anymore, you can only get messages of a Page with the conversations endpoint.